# Does external linking with internal link and redirect benefit the target website?

Tags: seo, redirects, backlinks

Suppose that website A inserts a link to website B. But it doesn't do it directly. It uses an internal link that redirect to website B. Considering SEO, does this link benefit website B? And what kind of redirect (301, 302 or 303) affects this behavior?

Comment: Are you talking about an app the redirects one link to another using à database?

Comment: @closetnoc That's one way do it. But it could be passing a parameter via url and use that. For example, http://WebsiteA.com/redirect?url=http://WebsiteB.com.

Comment: Along the same lines... Are you doing a 301? If so, then yes, it should work.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks. What about 303 redirects?

Comment: Not sure. Sorry. Cheers!!

Comment: While I cannot say for sure, upon reflection, I cannot see why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's benefits to target website, there are already bunch of website using like that.

```
www.mywebsite.com/redirect/www.someothersite.com
```

If you insert above link on your website(`www.mywebsite.com`) and it's redirect to `www.someothersite.com` then Google will also follow(unless it's not blocked under robots.txt) that redirection just like our browser do, because they use similar kind of webkit to render such a webpages.

Now affliate websites also do that, for example, `www.example.com/recommended/some-affliate-webpage/` but they block that recommended directory on their website via robots.txt, so the pagerank will not transfer to that affliate webpage. I don't know why you're asking this question, but if you have some kind of website like that and you don't want to transfer pagerank(Because of link spam) without using nofollow attribution then robots.txt is also better option.

There is also another example of webmasterworld forum. If you check that website then you will know they're not using nofollow attribution, but whenever any user insert the link it converts into internal links and then do redirection, like this `https://www.webmasterworld.com/r.cgi?f=30&d=4843612&url=https://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-console-link-no-data-available-23677.html` But their cgi directory is blocked under robots.txt so the Pagerank and other link matrics value will not going passed on `seroundtable.com` website.

[Regarding 30X, it all passes pagerank.](http://www.thesempost.com/google-all-redirects-pass-pagerank/)

Comment: Thanks. Actually website B is mine. I wanted to make sure that my website that is linked in website A with redirect, benefits. Referencing your link it seems that google doesn't care about redirects.

Comment: If website B is yours then I will check website A robots.txt to know weather they are blocking that directory or not /or using nofollow link or not. If they block it then you will not get any benefits, otherwise yes.