# External links to internal link and redirect

Tags: seo, redirects, links

There is s similar question for this ([Does external linking with internal link and redirect benefit the target website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105351/does-external-linking-with-internal-link-and-redirect-benefit-the-target-website?rq=1)) , but it is not extracly similar to this question and it did not give a answer for my question.

There are lots of external links in my website/blog. Now I need to analyze who clicks those links, how many times those links are clicked, etc.

Assume that my website is example.com.

I will **make** **all external links** as something like **below example**.

1. `example.com/go.php?external_link=https://stackoverflow.com`
2. `example.com/go.php?external_link=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/`

When user click a link I save all necessary data to database I will redirect user to real external page with 301 or 302.

Question 01: Should I use 301 or 302 for that redirection?

Question 02: Whatever redirection I use, is there bad affect for my site SEO wise?

Question 03: Is there bad affect for my site SEO wise, what is the solution for me?

Comment: Use 301. This is done all day every day for over a decade. No worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things involved in this question.

Firstly, if you feel that passing page rank (dofollow) is fine and you genuinely believed in linking those 3rd party sites then you may not want to do what you intend to do.

Generally, this kind of things are done in paid, affiliate marketing etc where you need to calculate the effectiveness of link, ad etc. And they are nofollow links.

**Assuming if you would change them as nofollow then different things can be done.**

Option 1: Do not ask Google to crawl go.php and do required as you wanted. Note that calculating and storing all these info will be just an overhead and may not be recommended.

Option 2: Do not let Google crawl go.php and let the page load with the message you are being redirected and have GA installed and it will give most of the info you may require.

Ensure to keep nofollow links in both scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by GA installed? Just adding GA code? Redirect should be 301 or 302?

Comment: GA: Google Analytics. If you link to go.php with nofollow then it wouldn't matter 301, 302 meta refresh etc.